# Push Notification without special characters - Windows Phone

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone

I have a problem with special characters in my Push Notification Message. I'm using externat server to recive messages. Unfortunalety I get message without special characters. When I send push from my application (example from msdn) all is right. I know that the server which send messages using utf8 and send the same message like example from msdn. Do you have any idea where is the problem ?